# Postgres Inner Join Select query returns error: column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been reading through the documentation and I can't find what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm executing this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "parts"
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "parts"."category_id"
WHERE "categories"."name" = "cars"
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  column "cars" does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE (categories.name = "cars")
                                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "cars" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 122
```

Category Table:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Parts Table:

```
CREATE TABLE parts
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  category_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT parts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use single apostrophes for string constants:

```
SELECT *
FROM "parts"
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "parts"."category_id"
WHERE "categories"."name" = 'cars'
```

The doubles mean db objects.(fields, tables, etc.)

(Otherwise they are not necessary, only for extras, for example spaces in names etc.)

Comment: Gah, something so simple.... Well thank you!!! I've been banging my head over this for a while.